# The mega menu stops working on certain pages of the website

Tags: megamenu

It's very strange. The mega menu works on most pages, for example: https://webhost.pro/support/

But once you load the cart pages or the client area pages, the menu stops working:
https://webhost.pro/cart.php?a=view

I just added the new mega menu code, it was working fine before this new mega menu was added today. Something I added is causing a conflict with certain parts of the website. I've tried to find any error codes or messages but there is none. I checked chrome's code errors and it didn't list any related to this.

The CSS code is pretty simple:

```
    /* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */
.dropdown-content {

  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  width: 100%;
  padding:20px 0px 20px 0px;
  z-index: 15;
}

.menu{background:#FFF;padding:35px 0;font-family:'Source Sans Pro',sans-serif}.menu .navbar-brand{padding:0}.menu .logo:hover{opacity:.5;transition:opacity .55s ease-in-out;-moz-transition:opacity .55s ease-in-out;-webkit-transition:opacity .55s ease-in-out}

.menu .navbar-nav .dropdown-menu{background:#FFF;margin-top:26px;border-radius:0;padding:0;border:1px solid #dedada;border-top:none}.menu .dropdown-item{color:#013d57;font-weight:600;font-size:12px;padding:10px 30px 10px 15px;text-transform:uppercase}
```

The menu code is:

```
    <!--Begin Menu-->
<div class="menu sticky-menu bridge">
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light"> <a class="navbar-brand" href="{$systemurl}"><img src="{$WEB_ROOT}/templates/{$child_template}/assets/img/logo.png" alt="web host pro" width="286" height="35" class="img-fluid logo" srcset="{$WEB_ROOT}/templates/{$child_template}/assets/img-retina/logo@2x.png 2x"></a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler custom-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-menu" aria-controls="main-menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation"> <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span> </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-menu">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <!--Begin Main Menu Item-->
          <li class="nav-item{if $filename eq 'contact' or $filename eq 'submitticket'} active{/if}"> <a class="nav-link" href="/index.php">Home</a></li>
          <!--End Main Menu Item--> 
          <!--Begin Main Menu Item-->
          </li><li class="nav-item .dropdown{if $category eq 'hosting'} active{/if}"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Services<i class="fas fa-fw fa-caret-down icon-dropdown"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-content">
                    <div class="row"> 
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{$WEB_ROOT}/services/website-builder/"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-server"style="color:#585453"></i>Website Builder</a></li>
                
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{$WEB_ROOT}/services/web-hosting/"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-server"style="color:#585453"></i>CPanel Web Hosting</a></li>
                
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{$WEB_ROOT}/services/reseller-hosting/"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-users"style="color:#585453"></i>Reseller Hosting</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{$WEB_ROOT}/services/vps-hosting/"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"style="color:#585453"></i>VPS Hosting</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{$WEB_ROOT}/services/dedicated-servers/"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"style="color:#585453"></i>Dedicated Servers</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{$WEB_ROOT}/domainchecker.php"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-globe"style="color:#585453"></i>Register a domain name</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{$WEB_ROOT}/cart.php?a=add&domain=transfer"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-globe"style="color:#585453"></i>Transfer a domain name</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://webhost.pro/services/ssl-certificates/"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-lock"style="color:#585453"></i>SSL certificates</a></li></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <section class="heromenu img-fluid"></div></ul></li>
          <!--End Main Menu Item--> 
          <!--Begin Main Menu Item-->
          <li class="nav-item .dropdown{if $category eq 'services'} active{/if}"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Support<i class="fas fa-fw fa-caret-down icon-dropdown"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-content">
                                    <div class="row"> 
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{$WEB_ROOT}/support/"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-life-ring"style="color:#000"></i><strong>Quick Help</strong></a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{$WEB_ROOT}/knowledgebase.php"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-book"style="color:#585453"></i>Knowledgebase</a></li>           
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{$WEB_ROOT}/submitticket.php"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-life-ring"style="color:#585453"></i>New Support Ticket</a></li>             
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{$WEB_ROOT}/supporttickets.php"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-life-ring"style="color:#585453"></i>View Support Tickets</a></li>  
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{$WEB_ROOT}/support/payment-options/"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-credit-card"style="color:#585453"></i>Payment Options</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{$WEB_ROOT}/support/how-to-build-a-website/"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-cogs"style="color:#585453"></i>Building a Website</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{$WEB_ROOT}/support/starting-a-website/"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-lightbulb"style="color:#585453"></i>Website Basics</a></li></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <section class="heromenu2 img-fluid">
                                    </div></ul></li>
          <li class="nav-item .dropdown{if $category eq 'services'} active{/if}"><a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Company<i class="fas fa-fw fa-caret-down icon-dropdown"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-content">
                                    <div class="row"> 
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{$WEB_ROOT}/company/why-us/"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-question-circle"style="color:#585453"></i>Why us</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{$WEB_ROOT}/company/about-us/"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-building"style="color:#585453"></i>About us</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{$WEB_ROOT}/company/affiliates/"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-sack-dollar"style="color:#119203"></i>Affiliate program</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{$WEB_ROOT}/contact.php"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-comments-alt"style="color:#585453"></i>Contacts</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="https://blog.webhost.pro/"><i class="fas fa-fw fa-pen"style="color:#585453"></i>Our Blog</a></li>
            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                                
                                <section class="heromenu3 img-fluid">
                                
                                    </div>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <!--End Main Menu Item--> 
          <!--Begin Main Menu Item-->
          {if $whmcs_menu eq 'integrated'}
          <li class="nav-item .dropdown{if $pagetype neq 'custom' and $filename neq 'index' and $filename neq 'contact' and $filename neq 'submitticket'} active{/if}"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Clients<i class="fas fa-fw fa-caret-down icon-dropdown"></i></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-content">
                                    <div class="row"> 
                        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                {include file="$child_template/{$zumada_content}/includes/client-navigation.tpl"}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                                
                                <section class="heromenu4 img-fluid">
                                
                            </div>
            </ul>
          </li>

          {else}
          <li class="nav-item .dropdown{if $pagetype neq 'custom' and $filename neq 'index' and $filename neq 'contact' and $filename neq 'submitticket'} active{/if}"> <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Clients<i class="fas fa-fw fa-caret-down icon-dropdown"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-content">
            {if $loggedin}
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{$WEB_ROOT}/clientarea.php"><i class="fas fa-user fa-fw"></i>{$LANG.account}</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{$WEB_ROOT}/logout.php"><i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt fa-fw"></i>{$LANG.clientareanavlogout}</a></li>
            {else}
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{$WEB_ROOT}/clientarea.php"><i class="fas fa-lock fa-fw"style="color:#119203"></i>{$LANG.login}</a></li>
                {if $condlinks.allowClientRegistration eq 'on'}
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{$WEB_ROOT}/register.php"><i class="fas fa-users fa-fw"></i>{$LANG.register}</a></li>
                {/if}
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="{$WEB_ROOT}/pwreset.php"><i class="fas fa-key fa-fw"></i>{$LANG.forgotpw}</a></li>
            {/if}
            </ul>
          </li>
          {/if}
          <!--End Main Menu Item-->
          <!--Begin Main Menu Item-->          <!--End Main Menu Item--> 
                <!--Begin Cart Link-->
          <li class="nav-item cart"><a href="{$WEB_ROOT}/cart.php?a=view"><span class="mobile-menu">View Cart</span><span class="cart-count"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
            <span class="btn btn-headercart">{$cartitemcount}</span>
          </span></a></li>
          <!--End Cart Link-->
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
<!--End Menu-->
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a conflict in the file:bridge.min.css

I removed the code from this CSS file and it's all good!

```
.bridge .dropdown,.bridge .dropleft,.bridge .dropright,.bridge .dropup{position:relative}.bridge .dropdown-toggle{white-space:nowrap}.bridge .dropdown-toggle::after{display:inline-block;margin-left:.255em;vertical-align:.255em;content:"";border-top:.3em solid;border-right:.3em solid transparent;border-bottom:0;border-left:.3em solid transparent}.bridge .dropdown-toggle:empty::after{margin-left:0}.bridge .dropdown-menu{position:absolute;top:100%;left:0;z-index:1000;display:none;float:left;min-width:10rem;padding:.5rem 0;margin:.125rem 0 0;font-size:1rem;color:#212529;text-align:left;list-style:none;background-color:#fff;background-clip:padding-box;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);border-radius:.25rem}.bridge .dropdown-menu-left{right:auto;left:0}.bridge .dropdown-menu-right{right:0;left:auto}@media (min-width:576px){.bridge .dropdown-menu-sm-left{right:auto;left:0}.bridge .dropdown-menu-sm-right{right:0;left:auto}}@media (min-width:768px){.bridge .dropdown-menu-md-left{right:auto;left:0}.bridge .dropdown-menu-md-right{right:0;left:auto}}@media (min-width:992px){.bridge .dropdown-menu-lg-left{right:auto;left:0}.bridge .dropdown-menu-lg-right{right:0;left:auto}}@media (min-width:1200px){.bridge .dropdown-menu-xl-left{right:auto;left:0}.bridge .dropdown-menu-xl-right{right:0;left:auto}}
```